# Is ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION required when enabling READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, read-committed-snapshot

Is it really necessary to enable `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` before enabling `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` as per [snapshot isolation level in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server)?.

Azure SQL created instances don't seem to have it enabled, despite their isolation level set to `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

I don't really understand whether `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is required at all or the consequences of it not being set before enabling `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`

I'm running into a deadlock in our production database which is hosted inside a VM.

> Transaction (Process ID XX) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

One of these transactions is a `SELECT` (holding an *S* lock) while the other one is an `INSERT` (holding an *IX* lock).

After trying to replicate this against a SQL Azure database that contains a backup of our production data I was unable until I realized that there was a difference in the isolation level (obtained through `DBCC USEROPTIONS`)

**Azure (SQLServer 12.0.2000.8):** *read committed snapshot*

**VM hosted (SQLServer 15.0.2080.9):** *read committed*

After matching the isolation level in the Azure DB by running `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF` I was able to reproduce the issue.

Now I want set *read committed snapshot* as our isolation level in the production database. The above mentioned link states that I need to run these two commands:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase  
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON  
  
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase  
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

However, it does not seem that snapshot isolation is allowed in the Azure DB (`SELECT snapshot_isolation_state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE NAME = 'MyDatabase'` returns *OFF*)

I'm also unable to find `tempdb` inside the System Databases in the Azure SQL instance.

Comment: `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` doesn't affect the isolation level unless `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` is used - using either though turns on row versioning in tempdb.

Comment: I am not using explicit transactions in my code and I am just using EF to run the queries. I am interested in just updating this setting for my DB so that EF can run with the default isolation level.

Comment: if `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is enabled (default in Azure) then that's all you need. RSCI reduces contention but deadlocks are still possible, writers still block writers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to enable ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION before
> enabling READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT as per snapshot isolation level in
> SQL Server?.
>
> Azure SQL created instances do not seem to have it enabled, despite
> their isolation level set to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT.

It is not necessary to enable `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` in order to enable `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` and visa-versa. `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is required only if you explicitly use `SNAPSHOT` isolation (`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`) whereas `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` changes the behavior of the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level (the default level) to use row-versioning instead of locking for statement-level read consistency.

Although both use row-versioning, an important difference is `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` returns a snapshot of data as of the time the statement began whereas the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level returns a snapshot of data as of the time the *transaction* began, an important consideration with a transaction containing multiple queries. Both will provide the same behavior for single-statement autocommit transactions.

Comment: Then how does READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT works? What is the difference to the ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION?

Comment: @LuisBecerril, I updated my answer to help answer your question. The doc link you referenced explains the difference in depth.

Comment: This article is also helpful to understand this difference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188277(v=sql.105)

Answer (score 0):

No, **`ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION`** is not required when enabling **`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` isolation level**.

When enabling **`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` isolation level**, you need to set **`READ_COMMITTED` isolation level** and turn on **`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`** with **the MSSQL command below**:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
GO
```

In addition, when enabling **`SNAPSHOT` isolation level**, you need to set **`SNAPSHOT` isolation level** and turn on **`ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION`** with **the MSSQL command below**:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
GO
```